# begin ... end key word pair in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I see a lot of usage in VHDL for "begin … end" pair, and the key word "begin" is never omitted in ARCHITECTURE and PROCESS structures even if there is only one statement (e.g. IF … ELSE … END IF or a simple statement). However, no key word "begin" is required in other three design units (ENTITY, CONFIGURATION, and PACKAGE) unless it is necessary.

Is this always a rule in VHDL? Are there any other situations that the key word "begin" has to be always used?

Comment: It's required for subprograms (`procedure` and `function`) and `block` statements. It's optional for `generate` statements.

Comment: VHDL's syntax is defined by the IEEE standard (e.g., IEEE Std 1076-2008, there are no -2019 compliant implementations as yet). An entity can have a `begin`, which separates  the optional entity header and entity declarative parts from the optional entity statement part (concurrent assertion statements and passive concurrent procedure calls) which would require an `end` as well. The syntax rules are expressed as an extended Backus Naur Form (BNF) also defined in the standard (VHDL is a formal notation). `begin` and `end` are part of the syntax and not statements

Comment: You'll find that subsets of VHDL's syntax are taught in classrooms. The standard also defines semantics - 1.3.3 Semantic description "The meaning and restrictions of a particular construct are described with a set of narrative rules immediately following the syntactic productions. In these rules, an italicized term indicates the definition of that term,...". You might feel the urge to add hundreds if not thousands of additional cross links to the PDF. VHDL has reserved words (15.10) not key words.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments here.

Comment: I wouldn't think of `begin`-`end` pairs in VHDL. I would think of 3-line VHDL constructs: `something`-`begin`-`end something;`. The `something` can be an `architecture` or `function` or `process`... It can also be an `entity` or `generate`, because the `begin` is optional with those two. The gap between `something` and `begin` is called the _declarative region_ and is where you declare things such as signals, variables, constants, functions, procedures... Declaring things is the only thing you can do in a package, so the whole thing is a declarative region - no `begin` is required.

Comment: The way Matt explained is also the way I am trying to understand and figuring out things by myself. It looks like if there is no declaration but only implementation (or procedures for execution), then "begin" is a must. O/W, you will get an error. I will double check the situation.

Comment: If a package needs both declaration and implementation (package body), such as a function being declared in a package, you will need the "begin" before you gives out the implementation for the function in the package.

Comment: I see that Mr. LRM has spoken. Unfortunately, VHDL is a highly inconsistent and illogical 'language' that doesn't adhere very well to the design principle of only having one version of the truth (e.g. entity-component copy-and-paste-plus-extra-indent). Historically, the language evolved during a time when people were trying to figure out the fundamentals of chip design. If you designed an HDL from scratch now, well... Altera (now Intel) tried to solve the problem with Altera HDL (AHDL). Others have moved away from VHDL (and Verilog) entirely with either their own in-house HDLs or C# CUDA, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussions here. I guess I may put out a bad question. Sorry.